# Upload and extract stopwatch into SQL Server database C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stopwatch

I try to upload into and extract stopwatch time from a SQL Server database with code shown below, but I get an error:

> "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'currentTimeVASN".

The code works fine if I remove the code for uploading and extracting stopwatch text into database

I posted the code below.

Appreciate your help.

```
public partial class TestWindowMLCC : Window
{
        String SNconnectionstring = (@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SNDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;");
        DispatcherTimer dtVASN = new DispatcherTimer();
        Stopwatch swVASN = new Stopwatch();
        string currentTimeVASN = string.Empty;

        public TestWindowMLCC()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void mlccSNCreate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConSN = new SqlConnection(SNconnectionstring))
            {
                sqlConSN.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlCmdSN = new SqlCommand("SNadd", sqlConSN);
                sqlCmdSN.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlCmdSN.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerialNumber", sNtxtbox.Text);
                sqlCmdSN.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Test1", SNTest1.Text.Trim());
                sqlCmdSN.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Test2", txtVASN.Text.Trim());
                sqlCmdSN.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("SN has been created! You may proceed to key in the data!");
            }
        }
        private void mlccOpen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConSN = new SqlConnection(SNconnectionstring))
            {
                sqlConSN.Open();
                String sqlSelectQuerySN = ("Select * FROM tblSN WHERE SerialNumber = @serialNumber");
                SqlCommand sqlCmdSNLoad = new SqlCommand(sqlSelectQuerySN, sqlConSN);
                sqlCmdSNLoad.Parameters.Add("@serialNumber", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sNtxtbox.Text;

                SqlDataReader drSNReader = sqlCmdSNLoad.ExecuteReader();               

                if (drSNReader.Read())
                {
                    SNTest1.Text = (drSNReader["Test1"].ToString());
                    txtVASN.Text = (drSNReader["currentTimeVASN"].ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    SNTest1.Text = "";
                    txtVASN.Text = "";
                    MessageBox.Show("The SN you keyed in is not exist. Please click Create Button to Create.");
                }
            }
        }

        private void sNbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mLCCTabControl.SelectedIndex = 1;
            dtVASN.Tick += new EventHandler(dtVASN_Tick);
            dtVASN.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
        }

        void dtVASN_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (swVASN.IsRunning)
            {
                TimeSpan tsVASN = swVASN.Elapsed;
                currentTimeVASN = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}",
                tsVASN.Hours, tsVASN.Minutes, tsVASN.Seconds);
                txtVASN.Text = currentTimeVASN;
            }
        }

        private void btnTimeStartSN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            swVASN.Start();
            dtVASN.Start();
        }

        private void btnTimeStopSN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (swVASN.IsRunning)
            {
                swVASN.Stop();
            }          
        }   
    }
}
```

Here is the contents of the SNAdd SP:

```
CREATE PROC SNadd @SerialNumber VARCHAR (50)
, @Test1 VARCHAR (50)
, @currentTimeVASN VARCHAR (50) 
AS 
INSERT INTO tblSN(SerialNumber,Test1,currentTimeVASN) VALUES (@SerialNumber,@Test1,@currentTimeVASN)
```

Comment: What line number is this error occurring on?

Comment: error came from this line:    txtVASN.Text = (drSNReader["currentTimeVASN"].ToString());

Comment: Can you publish the stored procedure SNadd?
This error is not a database error. I think your data reader is missing the 'currentTimeVASN' column. This is one reason you might get the index out of range error from .Net.

Comment: CREATE PROC SNadd
    @ SerialNumber VARCHAR (50),
    @ Test1 VARCHAR (50),
    @ currentTimeVASN VARCHAR (50)

    AS
    INSERT INTO tblSN(SerialNumber,Test1,currentTimeVASN)
    VALUES (@ SerialNumber,@ Test1,@ currentTimeVASN)     i purposely added space between after at symbol to allow the comment go thru.

Comment: Can you please publish the schema for the tblSN table?

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblSN] (
    [SerialNumber] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Test1]        VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [currentTimeVASN] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

Comment: Read this, then fix your problem... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader

Comment: Thanks for advice. however, i have read thru the webpage few times, but couldnt identify the cause of the issue. could you please specify a little bit more details? my appologies. i am very new to C#, just start self-learning it from scratch

Comment: The error you are getting means that "currentTimeVASN" is not findable in the datareader. Can you iterate over the columns names in the datareader and emit them? This would help ensure that there isn't a typo somewhere. The other way to do this is to use column index numbers instead of names. You could try doing that as well.

Comment: @DavidButtrick thank you very much for your help. You are right. The data table was not right and not properly updated as well due to some errors. the issue was able to be fixed. thank you again!